# Playing sounds NSDate in iOS (swift) when phone is locked

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an alarm clock app.

Assuming that the phone is sleeping (locked) but the app is in foreground, what is the best way to play sounds at a specific time? Obviously NSTimer wouldn't work when the device is sleeping... so how can I solve this issue? (Also, I don't want to use local notifications due to its limitations)

The apps "Nightstand" and "Sleep Cycle" seemed to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think, local notification is the best way. What type of limitation in local notification?

Comment: There are two problems that come to mind: 1) Cannot play sounds longer than 30 seconds. 2) If user switches ringer off then the sound doesn't play!

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/)? I believe if you add the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key to your plist you can have code that executes while the phone is locked.

Comment: Hi. I looked at it... but the problem is that I cannot run NStimer when the phone is locked. How can I play audio without limitations in a specific time when the phone is locked?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the answer thanks to bayowulf. and the following website: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/

Basically, opt out for multitasking (shows how to do in the website) and use NSTimer. Works great (with some limitations of course)!